# Power Autotmate - Flow works it reads all the the data from the SQL database, but does not create the newest item in SP list

Tags: office365, power-automate

My flow goes like this:
Manually trigger **->** Get rows(SQL database) **->** Apply to Each wrapper **->** Get items(SP) **->** Condition `length(body('Get_items')?['value']) is equal to 0` **->** if true **->** Create item(SP) **->** if false **->** nothing

[image]

The Flow is not creating the lates entry from my SQL database

It's getting data from an SQL database, and i want to check if the data is matching the items in my SP list.

i played around with the condition
and i when i do it like: `length(body('Get_items')?['value']) is not equal to 1`
then the flow never stops, which makes sense but i get my test entry into my SP List.

I hope someone has time to help.

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

[Here is the raw inputs coming from the database, the one with ID 52 is my test entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCGWp.png)

It returns "True" in the condition so the action to create item is "skipped"
If i then move the action under the "True" statement instead, that's when **my test item is created**, but it also creates an infinite loop, where it keeps creating items (duplicating) untill i manually stop it.

**UPDATE:**
[Flow looks like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US0OJ.png)

Using this expression on condition `length(body('Get_items')?['value']) is greater or equal to 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was

That i had to add a Filter Query to my "Get items", so that the flow checks if there is a *value in my SP list with the value from my database*
[Get items Filter Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGeDN.png)

Together with the Condition `length(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']) is greater or equal to 1`

The flow works as intended, it now ony creates the latest entry from my database

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the condition to:

```
length(body('Get_items')?['value']) is greater than or equal to 1
```

And then flip your actions round for True and False - so True do nothing, False create item.

I have a feeling (I can't test just now), that length(body('Get_items')?['value']) may return null if not present.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, i tried to play around with it but still not gettig nthe result i'm looking for, to only create the newest entry.

Comment: Looking at the flow run, follow the nth item and see where it drops out or doesn't work. In the `Apply to each` step, you should be able to navigate through each iteration.

Comment: hey i updated my post with an image and an explanation of what's happening.
maybe i have to look for another expression to filter out the duplicates ?

Comment: Why is there a `For each` around the `Create item`? And why does it go in an infinite loop? Very strange.

Comment: it is very strange i'm pretty new to Power Automate, but everywhere i've searched for a solution, it says the same "use this expression it'll solve the problem"
It's the same expression you gave me and it kinda seems to work.

But i feel like i'm very close and it's annoying af, that this little bit won't work.

The for each loop is neccesary to create all the items from the database, i just tried without it, it only created one item.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You're getting rows from SQL. Then you are looping through them with `Apply to each`,and in there for each row, you are checking if it is in SP. If not in SP, then create - so not sure why you need the `For each`. It would be helpful if for each step, you `Peek code` and share that in your question.

Comment: I removed the For Each to test and changed some data inputs, i then changed it back again, but it's not adding the for each again and can't even find it in list of actions. looks like it's just an action it adds whenever it thinks or is iteration over items.
The flow only takes the first entry from the database, but seems like this would be the way to go and try and fix it from here.

This little project to solve a company issue is taking why longer than anticipated, buti i'll get to the buttom of them somehow

Comment: Can your share the `Peek code` for the step `Create item` please.

Comment: I have updated my post in the buttom with the create item

Comment: omg i found the solution, i might a giant idiot but it's the time i've created anything in Power Automate.
well all i had to do was to add a Filter Query with - Blanketnummer(SP) eq blanketnummer(SQL)
it's done, i've checked with 2 different entries now it only created the newest one now no duplicates or anything.
i'll clean my psot a little and post the solution, it might help someone else.
thank you very much for your help